# How to add attribute to an input in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, zurb-foundation

I'm developing an app in cakePHP and I'd like to use [Foundation Tooltips](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html) into it.
I need to add data-tooltip to the input in order to make it work, but I don't know how to do it with the cakePHP form helper.

Right now I'm using:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title', (array( 'label' => __('title'),
                                               'class' => 'has-tip',
                                               'title' => __('Tooltip for initiative title'),
                                               )));
```

And is returning this:

```
<input name="data[Initiative][title]" class="has-tip" title="Tooltip for initiative title" maxlength="255" type="text" id="InitiativeTitle" required="required">
```

When I need this:

```
<input data-tooltip name="data[Initiative][title]" class="has-tip" title=...>
```

I've tried adding `'data-tooltip'`to the input array with no luck, but I'm sure it has to be an easy way of doing it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: will it work with <input data-tooltip="" > ??

Comment: you can add `'data-tooltip' => ''` to the array but this will generate `data-tooltip=""` in your input. Don't know if still could work

Comment: @arilia yes I was suggesting same

Comment: Now it's working with the empty data-tooltip, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title', array( 'label' => __('title'),
                                               'class' => 'has-tip',
                                               'title' => __('Tooltip for initiative title'),
                                               'data-tooltip'=>""
            ));
```

Comment: if he set 'data-tooltip' the attribute is not created at all in the input. If he set 'data-tooltip' => "" then the attribute created is data-tooltip = '' and we don't know if the tooltip will accept it